# How to rotate a player object based on mouse movement? (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like the horizontal movement of the mouse to cause the player to rotate on the y-axis. If it helps to explain, it should work like Minecraft, except you can't look up or down.

I have no idea where to even start doing this, except for that I need to add/subtract the rotation from the players transform component. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html learn to use quaternions in Unity. You will be able to handle any rotation problem with it.

Comment: Get the mouse position, check the difference with last frame. Base the amount of rotation on this and apply it.